# Limit of a summation

Tags: limits, sequences-and-series

I'm having trouble evaluating this limit:

$$
\lim_{x\to\infty} \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^n}{(n+a)}
$$

My intuition and initial attempts at making sense of it say that it diverges, and so do a few of my friends, but WolframAlpha says it equals $-\frac{1}{a}$ (if you plug in some values for $a$) and the intermediate steps for those are pretty useless.

For reference: [WolframAlpha's evaluation](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=lim%20x-%3Einfinity%20sum%20n=1%20to%20infinity%20%28x%5En%29/%28n%2b2%29)

Can anyone at least point me in the right direction on how to evaluate this limit?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The series diverges for every value of $x$ such that $|x|\ge1$ hence the limit when $x\to\infty$ is not defined.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The limit is increasing, so it is especially bigger than what you get for $x=1$ where it already diverges.

$\lim_{x\to\infty} \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^n}{(n+a)}>\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(n+a)}$

Wolfram alpha assumes first that $x$ is chosen in a manner that the sum converges and afterwards calculates the limit for $x$ towards infinity which is not what you want.

Comment: Though I clearly specify that $x\to\infty$.  Wouldn't WolframAlpha put out some message before making that assumption?

Comment: If you have $A(B)$ WolframAlpha first evaluates $B=C$ and then $A(C)$, in your case $B$ is the sum and $A$ the limit. Note that it sets $\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{x^n}{n+1}=\frac{-x-\log (1-x)}{x}$ which is only true if $|x|<1$

Comment: Ah, that explanation makes sense.  Thank you very much.

Comment: No problem, I agree that WolframAlpha can easily confuse you if you don't see how it evaluates expressions.

Answer (score 8):

It diverges. As soon as $x\geq 1$, we have
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{x^n}{n+a}\geq\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n+a}\geq\sum_{n=\lceil a\rceil+1}^\infty\frac{1}{n},$$
which differs from the (divergent) harmonic series by a finite amount. Thus the series is divergent for all $x\geq1$. I believe that Listing's explanation is correct, i.e. WolframAlpha is finding an [analytic continuation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_continuation) of the sum, then taking the limit. This is the same reason that $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}2^n$$ diverges, but $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n=\frac{1}{1-x}$$
and $\frac{1}{1-x}$ is defined for all $x\neq 1$ (e.g. $\frac{1}{1-2}=-1$).

Comment: But how does this explain what WolframAlpha is doing?  Is it making a mistake?

Comment: @kevm0314: Could you provide a link / post the commands you are using in Wolfram Alpha?

Comment: Yes, added it to the original post if this link doesn't work:  http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=lim%20x-%3Einfinity%20sum%20n=1%20to%20infinity%20%28x%5En%29/%28n%2b2%29

Comment: @kevm0314: Thanks for the link. I've added to my answer.

Comment: Ah I wish I could accept multiple answers.  Both of your answers were incredibly helpful.  Thanks so much!

Comment: @kevm0314: No problem, glad to help!

Answer (score 1):

Another way to see that it diverges for $x > 1$ is seeing that the general term does not go to $0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$ because 
$$
\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{x^n}{n+a} = \infty
$$